# Two questions on Shor's algorithm

Tags: quantum-computing

Does Shor's algorithm produce factors of a $n$-bit number and discrete log modulo $n$-bit prime in $O((\log n)^{2+\epsilon})$ bit operations using fast multiplication? I am trying to read from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shor%27s_algorithm). If not what is the 'right' number of comparable 'bit' operations in the classical model?

What is the hidden constant in $O((\log n)^{2+\epsilon})$?

As far as we know the $2$ in the exponent could be brought down to $1$. There have been many techniques in classical factoring/discrete log calculation that tried to reduce complexity over many decades. Has there been any attempt to bring the exponent from $2$ down to $1$? Or is there a proof that $2$ is the best that can be done?

Comment: Could you provide the reference for that bound?

Comment: Yes, people have tried to bring the exponent on the $\log$ down. And there's no proof that 2 is the best possible.

Comment: @PeterShor Thank you is there a reference on such attempted lower bounds or upper bounds?

Comment: Since people don't usually write up unsuccessful attempts, one wouldn't expect to find references.

Comment: @PeterShor Thank you. Is the hidden constant very small?

Comment: @PeterShor I think $2$ cannot be lowered.